# simple calculator app, presents SIGABRT error when I add new button

Tags: ios, sigabrt

I'm new to Objective-C programminga nd X-Code so please bear with me. I copied code from a book about objective C to make a calculator class and it's working wonders. Then it asked me as part of the exercises to add a convert button to convert a fraction to a double and print it. The thing is that when I press the convert button, the app stops and I get a message saying that the program received a SIGABRT signal.

Here is the button code:

```
-(IBAction)clickConvert //convert method
{
if ( [myCalculator accumulator] != 0 ){
    displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%e", [myCalculator convertResult]];

    display.text = displayString;

    [displayString setString:@""];
}}
```

The convertResult code:

```
 -(double) convertResult 
{
double convertedFraction;
convertedFraction = [accumulator convertToNum];

return convertedFraction;
}
```

(accumulator is a Fraction object that contains the value of the mathematical operation done on the 2 operands)

and the ConverToNum function:

```
 -(double) convertToNum
{
if (denominator != 0)
    return (double) numerator/denominator;
else
    return NAN;
 }
```

everything else in teh app works fine, so it must be a problem with what I've done......can anyone help? I've been searching online all day, but I read completely different stuff about this SIGABRT error. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide the error message that is logged in the XCode console. That will provide more insight into what is wrong.

Comment: add an exception breakpoint , aslo make sure the button is linked to your XIB the right way

Comment: Nothing useful really. Just this: GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug 15 16:03:10 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 967.
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: What's the right way? I just CTRL+click+drag to the function

Comment: Ok found it. After adding an exception breakpoint. It was the "[displayString setString:@""];" methods fault. But it doesn't make sense, since I called it for another button and there it works :S. Anyway, thanks for hte help guys :)

Comment: you need to improve your basics. - start reading at www.codigator.com or at www.raywenderlich.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `displayString` is an `NSString`, then there is no `setString` setter.  Just assign the string to `displayString`.

Instead of

```
[displayString setString:@""]
```

do:

```
displayString = @"";
```

Edit:

You say that `displayString` is an `NSMutableString`.  In that case, your first assignment to `displayString`:

```
displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%e", [myCalculator convertResult]];
```

assigns an immutable object to the displayString pointer.  I don't know why the compiler isn't complaining about that.  Then when you try to call `setString` on `displayString`, the actual type of the object is `NSString` even though you have declared the pointer to be an `NSMutableString`.  To fix this, try:

```
displayString = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%e", [myCalculator convertResult]] mutableCopy];
```

or:

```
[displayString setString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%e", [myCalculator convertResult]]];
```

or:

```
displayString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%e", [myCalculator convertResult]];
```

Comment: This is correct. The `setString:` method is only available for an `NSMutableString` object, not for `NSString`'s.

Comment: But displayString IS a NSMutableString

Comment: Interesting that it is an `NSMutableString`.  Did you try the assignment anyway.  That should work for a mutable string as well.  Also, you never did say what the error message was after you added the exception breakpoint.  Could you post the exact text of the error message you are receiving.

Comment: When I try the assignment like this displayString = @"" it gets an error saying: Incompatible pointer types assinging to NSMutableString *_strong from NSString     ........I'll get back to you with the error message

Comment: Ah.  You could do `displayString = [@"" mutableCopy];` then.  Still curious about the other error message though.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :). Honestly I have no idea. The debbuger console just printed that GNU legal stuff :S. Anyway, thanks for all your help guys, you're the greatest :D

Comment: I just updated my answer to explain the problem.  See the edit.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click the check mark under the answer number to mark it as the correct answer.